# mysql show child data

Tags: mysql, select, foreign-keys

I need sql script to print all child data for good.id but no idea how

in DB I have tables good and good_translation
good table is parent to good_translation (i think so)

```
mysql> desc good_translation;
    +-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id              | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | translatable_id | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
    | title           | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | announce        | varchar(1024) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
..............
    | format          | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | composition     | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    | language        | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
    +-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    25 rows in set (0.07 sec)
    
    
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `good_translation`;
    /*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
    CREATE TABLE `good_translation` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `translatable_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `announce` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
..............
      `format` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `composition` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `language` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `good_translation_unique_translation` (`translatable_id`,`locale`),
      KEY `IDX_BBB702302C2AC5D3` (`translatable_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `FK_BBB702302C2AC5D3` FOREIGN KEY (`translatable_id`) REFERENCES `good` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1577 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
    /*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

Comment: I get script with my functionality. It do what me need but need to learn why :)
select 
  *
from 
  good g 
  join good_translation t
    on g.id = t.translatable_id
where
  g.id = 25;

Comment: The question asking for a solution but you didn't tried anything

Comment: I get answer in  other place  (first comment). difficult is for me to use right words in my   googling. frendly forum friends give me answer and now i know way to result. but no result on my hands